# Track status change and date of change in longitudinal data

Tags: r

I am trying to report chronological updates on whether participants in an ongoing study ever suffered car crash injuries. Suppose I am following a growing cohort of food delivery drivers and am tracking the severity of car crash injuries. Injuries for each crash are coded as none, minor, or severe. Any driver with a prior crash injury is excluded from entering the study. All data reflect incidents that occurred after study entry.

For each calendar quarter starting from the earliest observation, I’d like to report the number of drivers who crashed but (1) never sustained an injury; (2) ever sustained only minor injuries; and (3) ever sustained at least 1 severe injury. Assume that each crash results in no more than one injury. Once a driver sustains an injury, the severity of that injury will continue to get reported unless it is replaced by a more severe injury. Each driver should only be represented once per quarter. E.g., if a driver experienced multiple types of crash injuries in the same quarter, only one occurrence of the most severe injury classification should be reported.

Here is my data set:

```
df <- data.frame(
  DriverID = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
         'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
         'C',
         'D', 'D', 'D',
         'E', 'E'),
  study_entry = as.Date(c('2020-01-13', NA, NA, NA, NA,
                    '2020-03-02', NA, NA, NA,
                    '2020-04-15',
                    '2020-10-08', NA, NA,
                    '2020-07-20', NA)),
  crash_date = as.Date(c(NA, '2020-03-03', '2020-05-01', '2020-07-28', '2020-11-20',
                    NA, '2020-07-10', '2020-08-19', '2020-12-25',
                    NA,
                    NA, '2020-10-10', '2020-11-23',
                    NA, '2020-09-30')),
  crash_severity = c(NA, 'N', 'M', 'S', 'M', 
               NA, 'M', 'S', 'N',
               NA,
               NA, 'S', 'M',
               NA, 'N')
  )
```

Visually, the data might look like:

```
 |--Y1Q1--|--Y1Q2--|--Y1Q3--|--Y1Q4--|
A *    N     M       S            M
B      *            M   S           N
C              *        
D                            * S  M
E                    *         N

*: Entry into study
N: Non-injury crash
M: Minor-injury crash
S: Severe-injury crash
```

I’d like to be able to create the table below. Note that for each reporting period, the severity of future injuries is not reflected.

```
Period  Drivers  N   M   S  
Y1Q1      2      1   0   0
Y1Q2      3      0   1   0
Y1Q3      4      0   0   2
Y1Q4      5      1   0   3
```

Comment: you start out by saying: "Any driver with a prior crash injury is excluded from entering the study." And then you have all these conditional rules about prior crashes?

Comment: Perhaps its a Heisenberg effect, once in the study they start having all kinds of crashes.

Comment: @IRTFM: This is made-up data, so the frequency of crashes may seem absurd. I added the bit about the exclusion criterion in an attempt to make clear that all participants at the start of the study should be considered to have never crashed. The conditional rules apply to crashes observed during the study period.

Comment: @epiguy: I wasn't saying the data was malformed (since I never got to it). I was saying that your natural language description of the task was internally contradictory. I expect  need to edit it rather than trying to make excuses.

Comment: This is a common recruitment strategy for epidemiological studies. To be eligible for the study, the driver must not have had a crash before entering the study. @epiguy, if I understand correctly, tracks the severity of crashes after they have been recruited.

Comment: @mikebader: You are correct--thanks for chiming in.

Comment: @IRTFM: I included one more sentence that I hopes makes this clearer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I came up with using `tidyverse`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
firstdates <- df %>%
    group_by(DriverID, crash_severity) %>%
    arrange(crash_date) %>%
    slice_min(crash_date) %>%
    filter(!is.na(crash_date)) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = "DriverID", names_from = "crash_severity", values_from = "crash_date")

quarters <- tribble(
    ~quarter, ~enddate,
    "Y1Q1", "2020/03/31",
    "Y1Q2", "2020/06/30",
    "Y1Q3", "2020/09/30",
    "Y1Q4", "2020/12/31"
) %>%
    mutate(enddate = as.Date(enddate))

df3 <- df %>%
    select(DriverID, study_entry) %>%
    group_by(DriverID) %>%
    slice(rep(1, nrow(quarters))) %>%
    mutate(!!!quarters) %>%
    filter(study_entry < enddate) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    left_join(firstdates, by = "DriverID") %>%
    mutate(
        crash = if_else(N < enddate, "N", "X"),
        crash = if_else(M < enddate, "M", crash),
        crash = if_else(S < enddate, "S", crash),
        crash = replace_na(crash, "X")
    ) %>%
    group_by(quarter, crash) %>%
    count() %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = "quarter", names_from = "crash", values_from = "n") %>%
    mutate(across(matches("[SMNX]"), ~replace_na(., 0))) %>%
    mutate(drivers = rowSums(across(matches("[SMNX]"))))
df3
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   quarter [4]
  quarter     N     X     M     S drivers
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Y1Q1        1     1     0     0       2
2 Y1Q2        0     2     1     0       3
3 Y1Q3        0     2     0     2       4
4 Y1Q4        0     2     0     3       5
```

The `firstdates` tibble contains a column for each level of severity with values equal to the date of the first crash of that severity.

We then create containing all of the quarters in the study with the last day of each quarter and repeat that dataset for every driver. We keep rows where the end date of the quarter came after the driver's entry into the study. We then merge the data on the first date of each type of crash and create the variable `crash`. The variable contains a letter indicating the most severe incident that occurred before the end date of that quarter with `"X"` standing for no crash having occurred.

After that we summarize the data by crash type and sum across the columns to calculate the number of drivers in the study (note the lack of an "M" column reflects the fact that all moderate crashes occurred after the driver already experienced a severe crash).

Comment: Thank you so much!! I appreciate you doing this in tidyverse, as I'm trying to get more familiar with it. I noticed that in creating the `firstdates` tibble, `slice(n())` selected the last row (i.e., most recent date). I did some digging and was able to get the earliest date using `slice_min(crash_date, n=1)`. Thanks again for your time and contributions!

Comment: For Y1Q2, the tabulation should include a column for "M", as there is one instance of a minor injury crash (Subject A on 2020-05-01). Subject A's status will later be replaced by "S" when they experience a severe injury crash on 2020-07-28. I believe the fix lies in the nested `if_else` statements when creating the `crash` variable. I haven't been successful yet but will continue to work on this.

Comment: I actually think that you solved it yourself by using `slice_min(crash_date)`. For some reason the slice wasn't taking the correct crash date. I edited the answer. Also, I changed the if-else logic to be clearer.

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate the edits you made after posting your solution.